# kubernetes rolling update time interval

Tags: kubernetes

I put elasticsearch in the kubernetes cluster as statefulset.
When I using rollingUpdate to updte the statefulset.
I got a problem, k8s restart the elasticsearch node and think it's ready, and then move on to next node, however, the node is not ready in elasticsearch cluster. The es cluster sitll yellow even red.

So is there any options such like time interval when rollingUpdate ??

Or is there some configuration of minimal time of probing pod ready ??

Now I use onDelete strategy to update the es, manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the best thing you can do is to implement a readinessProbe https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes. As long as it returns not ready the Pod will be in not ready state and next pod will not be rolled.